# Why does $?.exited? return an incorrect value after system() when I/O redirection is used?

Tags: ruby, process

I'm trying to execute a program using the `system` function in Ruby.
I need to capture the stdout and stderr of the program, so I'm using
a shell command that redirects stdout and stderr to files.
One important requirement is that I need to determine whether
the program exited normally or was killed by a signal.

The weird behavior I'm seeing is that when I redirect stdout and
stderr to files, `$?.exited?` is true even if the program was
killed by a signal!  Here is a program that demonstrates the
problem:

```rb
#! /usr/bin/ruby

File.open("bad.c", "w") do |out|
    out.print <<'EOF'
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int *p = 0;
    *p = 42;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
EOF
end
raise "Couldn't compile bad.c" unless system("gcc -o bad bad.c")

system("./bad");
puts $?.exited?

system("./bad > out 2> err");
puts $?.exited?
```

The output of this program is

```
false
true
```

However, I would expect

```
false
false
```

since the program is killed by a segfault in both cases.

The command `ruby -v` produces the output

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

Any explanations and/or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are performing shell redirection on the second `system()` call, ruby needs to invoke your shell to do the work. Even though your program is being killed, the shell ends up executing just fine.

You can, instead, do the redirection directly in ruby:

```
system("./bad", out: 'out', err: 'err');
puts $?.exited? # => false
```

For more options, check out the documentation for [`spawn()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) - the options on `system()` are processed the same way.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thanks! As it turned out, I still needed to use the shell (to use ulimit to set process limits), but I changed the shell command so that it ended with an exec to execute the actual program.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: @DavidHovemeyer I suggest you take a look at the documentation I linked to. You can set the limits from the `system()` call as well, using the `:rlimit_resourcename` option ;)